# React save the value of current state and make it unchangeable

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I have a problem considering saving the value of current state. I am not sure if it is possible.

To summarise, I have build up a function which returns a HTML element as below. The idea is to save a div on each click.

```
createQuestion(){
        let CurrentQuestion=this.state.freetextinput;
        return this.state.values.map((el, i) => 
         <div key={i} className="QuestionBox">
            {CurrentQuestion}
         </div>          
        )
    }
```

The value of freetextinput changes on each click. The idea is to save all the value of freetextinput. Say, the values of freetextinput are 1, 2, 3. I would like to have all of the three values:

```
1
2
3
```

However, I only get something like this:

```
3
3
3
```

I wonder, if there is a way to save/store the value of this.state.freetextinput, such that I can get all the three values.

Comment: so the free text input is for every question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new question needs to be pushed into an array before it can be mapped. Might something like this work for you?

```
var savedQuestions = []

createQuestion(q){        
  savedQuestions.push(q)
  this.setState({savedQuestions: savedQuestions}, () => {
    var questionElements = this.state.savedQuestions.map((el, i) => 
     <div key={i} className="QuestionBox">
        {el}
     </div>          
    )
    })
    return questionElements
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save every input of free text input into an array, that way you would get access to all the values:

You can check this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j835121kv

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the value of free text input is given by the user input, I cannot define the value in advance. :(

Comment: i would suggest to store all the previous values of free text input in an array kind of datastructure that way you can get accesst to all the values

Comment: This could be a good idea. But - sorry I am really new to React - how could I save the value in the array? I mean, when I try to save the value, I would use something like setState({QuestionID1: this.state.freetextinput}). But then each time a append the array, the other values are changed too, right? Because they are all defined as this.state.freetextinput.

Comment: @ShaLi please accept or upvote if my answer helped you :)

Comment: Geeky: in general, we recommend that answers contain code or an explanation of the solution as well as a link. Your post offers a sentence of assistance, but I wonder, are you able to expand that? It is a bit brief at the moment, and nearly a link-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should map `this.state.freetextinput` directly :

Since `freetextinput` is a string, you will need to convert it to an array first using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
createQuestion(){
    return this.state.freetextinput.split(', ').map(el =>
        <div key={el} className="QuestionBox">
            {el}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will work if your string looks like : `"1, 2, 3"`
If your string is `"123"` then use `split('')` instead of `split(', ')`

Comment: I have tried it, but it returns "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.freetextinput.map...')"

Comment: What is `freetextinput` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think the problem is that my freetextinput is not an array. :(

Comment: It is a value (string) given by the user input, in my code value comes from setState

Comment: I tried to give a user input, if it is valid input i am tring to push the value to an array , in that way i am saving the values, hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much!! It looks great! I am trying to adjusting it to my code!